# max retries exceeded django getstream

Tags: python, django, getstream-io

after integrate with getstream.io with django, and few click on follow - unfollow some people i have this error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.stream-io-api.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1.0/feed/timeline/1/follows/user:3/?api_key=1234567 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f78d423e828>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

First clicks works good but after that I have this error.

Comment: Could it be rate throttling? Are you calling this a lot?

Comment: I have 2 api calls in getstream dashboard and then this show up.

Comment: It works fine for 2 calls, then this shows up? ..then you wait a bit and it works again? Sounds like throttling on their end. Ive never used their service, so im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that something is going wrong with the resolution of the API domain name.

This can be caused by a bad internet connection, bad DNS configuration or nameservers. My suggestion is to change your DNS settings to Google's (8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4) or Cloudflare (1.1.1.1 / 1.0.0.1) and try again Stream APIs.

Keep in mind that in most cases DNS resolution is cached by the operating system, you might need to flush that cache and/or run the test longer than DNS cache TTL (1 minute).

Comment: Thanks! Work now :) I just change local domain for dev (using nanobox.io) and problem solved.